# Wrong account displayed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-account

I have a google GSuite account and a free gmail account.

Whilst viewing a sheet and signed in to my GSuite account, I select Tools -> Script Editor and it displays my free gmail account in the top right corner. Why isn't this displaying my GSuite account?

Comment: Is that in the top right corner of the browser?If you Gsuite Account is synced with your Gmail account then I think that's what that logo is.

Comment: just click on your gmail account name (below) and you'll be prompted to continue with the other one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are signed in multiple accounts and your default account is the gmail account.

IMHO the best is better to avoid the use of the multiple sign-in feature. You could set one web browser profile for each account.